# Azure Graph API Filter by array value

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to execute an query on my users of my Azure B2C Active Directory.

So far everything works fine with the following query:

```
https://graph.windows.net/myTentant/users?$filter=
startswith(displayName,'test')%20
or%20startswith(givenName,'test')%20
or%20startswith(surname,'test')%20
or%20startswith(mail,'test')%20
or%20startswith(userPrincipalName,'test')
&api-version=1.6
```

The thing about that is, that this properties are just simple values like this:

```
"displayName: "testValue",
"givenName": "testValue",
"displayName: "testValue",
"surname": "testValue",
"mail: "testValue",
"userPrincipalName": "testValue",
```

In my case I need to use one more statement, in which I need to check an array if it contains 'test' like the others. This array look like that:

```
        "signInNames": [
            {
                "type": "emailAddress",
                "value": "test@mail.com"
            },                {
                "type": "emailAddress",
                "value": "test2@mail.com"
            }
        ]
```

I Already search in the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations) but had no luck....
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, we should use the following format to determine whether the value starts with "test".

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?$filter=signInNames/any(c:startswith(c/value, 'test'))
```

Unfortunately, it will show an error: **value only supports equals-match. PrefixMatch is not supported**.

And the `contains` string operator is currently not supported on any Microsoft Graph resources. So we can't use `contains` neither.

You need to use `equal` to find the exact match data：

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?$filter=signInNames/any(c:c/value eq '***')
```

It is not a solution. But there seems not to be a way to meet your needs.

Maybe you could query all the signInNames and handle them in your code.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer! Your right, it's not excatly what I'm looking for, but it helps me out to find user by there complete mail-adress.